# Problem with my Jquery function dosent call controllerside method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have these codes in my Razor which already was working but now it doesn't works:

```
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Pcode" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Pcode" class="form-control" id="UserCode" name="UserCode" onchange="UserCheck()" style="background-color:lightyellow" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Pcode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p id="Status" name="Status" />

            </div>
        </div>
```

these are my code in jquery function :

```
  $.noConflict();
function UserCheck()
{
    $("#Status").html("Checking ...");
    $.post("@Url.Action("CheckIfUserCodeExist", "Leave")",
    {
    UserCode: $("#UserCode").val(),
    },
    function (data) {
    if (data) {
    $("#Status").html(data);
    @*$("#Status").html('@TempData["NF"]');*@
    $("#UserCode").css("border-color", "Green");
    }
    else {
    $("#Status").html('<font color="Red">این شخص قبلا ثبت نام نشده </font>');
    $("#UserCode").css("border-color", "Red");
    }
    });
    }
```

and here are my code in controller side:

```
 public JsonResult CheckIfUserCodeExist(Int32 UserCode)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        var SearchData = db.Persons.Where(x => x.Pcode == UserCode).SingleOrDefault();
        TempData.Remove("NF");
        //TempData.clear();
        if (SearchData != null)
        {
            string N = SearchData.Name;
            string F = SearchData.Family;
            TempData["code"] = UserCode;
            var NF = N + " " + F;
            //TempData["NF"] = NF;
            return Json(NF);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["code"] = 0;

            return Json("");
        }
    }
```

would you please help me where is the problem? I tested this several time without error.but now ....

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of the JS part.

Comment: Did you checking browsers developer tools for any error being logged and the network tab to see what response you are getting for the AJAX call? do you have [httppost] added on top of the controller action?